# Calculate hours difference with another timezone

Tags: java, jodatime

If I have a timezone e.g. “GMT-05:00”
How can I find how many hours is the difference with my current location using Joda?
I am using this code:

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT" + gmtTZ);     
int offset = tz.getOffset((new DateTime().getMillis()));     
System.out.println(“— > “+offset / 3600000d);
```

Gives me -5, but it does not take into account the time difference of my timezone.

Comment: I'm sorry, perhaps I simply misunderstand, but how is the -5 unexpected?

Comment: How about getting your local timezone (`TimeZone.getDefault()`), doing the same calculation, then subtracting the two?

Comment: @MrHug:No because I am 7 hours ahead

Comment: @AndyTurner:I get 0 with this approach

Comment: @Jim Are you sure your JVM's default timezone is set correctly?

Comment: @AndyTurner:You are right it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation of `getOffset` method. Millis from date does not contain any information about timezone and `getOffset` takes millis parameter in order to tell if this particular date is within daylight saving time. And if it is you will get one hour more. The way you are doing it you will never get a difference, your result can only be -5/-4 hours.

You do not even need JodaTime:

```
TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-5");
TimeZone localTimeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();

int timeZoneOffset = timezone.getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis());
int localTimeZoneOffset = localTimeZone.getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis());

int difference = Math.abs(timeZoneOffset - localTimeZoneOffset ) / 3600000;
```

If you want JodaTime just replace `System.currentTimeMillis()` with `DateTime.now().getMillis()` but I do not see the point other than testability.

Comment: It would be better to get the current time once (by either method) and use in both calls to getOffset. The difference is minor, but more correct.

Comment: Perhaps lamen question but why `TimeZone.getDefault();` would return the default timezone in GMT and not e.g. in UTC?

Comment: I've never written that ```TimeZone.getDefault()``` will return GMT. Read the javadoc. Generally it is returning timezone of your machine but not always -> read the javadoc

Comment: So basically I shouldn't care about if this calculation is among different timezones? E.g. "GMT-5" and local is UTC? It is handled transparently right?